# Using a regular expression backreference as part of the regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to using part of a regular expression as input for a later part of the regular expression.

What I have so far (which fails the assertions):

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r"(?P<length>\d+)(\d){(?P=length)}")
assert bool(regex.match("3123")) is True
assert bool(regex.match("100123456789")) is True
```

Breaking this down, the first digit(s) signify how many digits should be matched afterward. In the first assertion, I get a `3`, as the first character, which means there should be exactly three digits after, otherwise there are more than 9 digits. If there are more than 9 digits, then the first group will need to be expanded and checked against the rest of the digits.

The regular expression `3(\d){3}` would properly match the first assertion, however I cannot get the regular expression to match the general case where the braces `{}` are fed a regular expression backreference: `{(?P=length)}`

Calling the regular expression with the `re.DEBUG` flag I get:

```
subpattern 1
  max_repeat 1 4294967295
    in
      category category_digit
subpattern 2
  in
    category category_digit
literal 123
groupref 1
literal 125
```

It looks like the braces `{` (`123`) and `}` (`125`) are being interpreted as literals when there is a backreference inside of them.
When there is no backreference, such as `{3}`, I can see that `{3}` is being interpreted as `max_repeat 3 3`

Is using a backreference as part of a regular expression possible?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't put a backreference inside a quantifier. That's the life.

Comment: You can only use backreferences in actual match text, not inside things like repeat quantifiers or character classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to put the backreference as a limiting quantifier argument inside the pattern. To solve your current task, I can suggest the following code (see inline comments explaining the logic):

```
import re
def checkNum(s):
    first = ''
    if s == '0':
        return True # Edge case, 0 is valid input
    m = re.match(r'\d{2,}$', s) # The string must be all digits, at least 2
    if m:
        lim = ''
        for i, n in enumerate(s):
            lim = lim + n
            if re.match(r'{0}\d{{{0}}}$'.format(lim), s):
                return True
            elif int(s[0:i+1]) > len(s[i+1:]):
                return False

print(checkNum('3123'))         # Meets the pattern (123 is 3 digit chunk after 3)
print(checkNum('1234567'))      # Does not meet the pattern, just 7 digits
print(checkNum('100123456789')) # Meets the condition, 10 is followed with 10 digits
print(checkNum('9123456789'))   # Meets the condition, 9 is followed with 9 digits
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/qUEIvJ).

The pattern used with `re.match` (that anchors the pattern at the start of the string) is `{0}\d{{{0}}}$` that will look like `3\d{3}$` in case the `3123` is passed to the `checkNum` method. It will match a string that starts with `3`, and then will match exactly 3 digits followed with end of string marker (`$`).

Comment: What about validating groups that are 9+ digits? 1501234567890 should be false.

Comment: I thought they should pass. Please make the question a bit clearer in that regard. Just remove the first part in the `checkNum` method.

Comment: I can see how my wording would make it confusing. I was trying to attempt to highlight the context sensitive nature of the string.

Comment: Well, the point is that you need to get the necessary data for regex building first, and then build the pattern dynamically.

Comment: Based on your answer, I can see how to do this for n digits. Take the length of the digits string and split it into two parts based on `len(str(len(s)-1))` and `len(s) - len(str(len(s)-1))`

I ended up doing a kind of backtracking through counting digit characters.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. The first n digits may be the limiting quantifier argument.

Comment: Yes exactly. My comment-example fails for 99+ length strings by the way.

Comment: Please check my latest edit, however "crude" it is, the solution should work. It now checks if a string is all digits, and then checks the string acc. to your requirements.